Combining the Probability of an Event happening
I am wondering how best to combine a series of probabilities. I have an event that has a different probability of happening on each day, I was wondering how best to combine them for the weekly probability. For instance the probability of an event happening on:
Sunday = 0.005%
Monday = 0.025%
Tuesday = 0.003%
Wednesday = 0.005%
Thursday = 0.007%
Friday = 0.009%
Saturday = 0.010%
Each day is theoretically independent of every other day. Do I multiply the probabilities together? Add them? Probabilities have never been my strong suit.

do you want to know the probability of the event happening on any day, or happening every day, or something else?

The probability that the next three Mondays the event is happening is $0.00025^3=25^3\cdot 10^{-15}$, if the probability for each weak remains the same.

Zoe - I’m looking for what is the probability that the event would happen that week.

Let $p_i$ be the probability of an event occurring on the $i$th day of the week for $i\in\{1,2,3,...,7\}$. Then, the probability of the event not occurring on the $i$th day is $1-p_i$. This is derived by the complement rule.
We can find the probability of the event occurring at least once during the week by first calculating the probability of the event $not$ occurring during the whole week and then calculating the complement of this quantity.
Assuming independence of events, the probability of the event not occurring during the whole week is $\prod_{i=1}^7 (1-p_i) =(1-p_1)(1-p_2)(1-p_3)(1-p_4)(1-p_5)(1-p_6)(1-p_7)$. This is derived by the chain rule and further simplified by the definition of independence. The complement of this quantity is simply $ 1 - {\prod}_{i=1}^7 (1-p_i) $.
Thus, generally speaking, the probability of the event occurring at least once during the week is given by $ 1 - \prod_{i=1}^7 (1-p_i) $. If we have the probabilities as follows
$
\begin{array}{llll}
\text{DAY OF WEEK} & \text{PROBABILITY OF EVENT} \\
\text{Sunday} & p_1 = \text{0.005%} = \frac{0.005}{100} = 0.00005 \\
\text{Monday} & p_2 = \text{0.025%} = \frac{0.025}{100} = 0.00025 \\
\text{Tuesday} & p_3 = \text{0.003%} = \frac{0.003}{100} = 0.00003 \\
\text{Wednesday} & p_4 = \text{0.005%} = \frac{0.005}{100} = 0.00005 \\
\text{Thursday} & p_5 = \text{0.007%} = \frac{0.007}{100} = 0.00007 \\
\text{Friday} & p_6 = \text{0.009%} = \frac{0.009}{100} = 0.00009 \\
\text{Saturday} & p_7 = \text{0.01%} = \frac{0.01}{100} = 0.0001 \\
\end{array}
$
then the probability of the event occurring at least once during the week is
$ 1 - \prod_{i=1}^7 (1-p_i) = 1-(1-p_1)(1-p_2)(1-p_3)(1-p_4)(1-p_5)(1-p_6)(1-p_7) $
$ = 1-(1-0.00005)(1-0.00025)(1-0.00003)(1-0.00005)(1-0.00007)(1-0.00009)(1-0.0001) $
$ = 1-(0.99995)(0.99975)(0.99997)(0.99995)(0.99993)(0.99991)(0.9999) $
$ = 1-0.9993601591 = 0.0006398409204$

Perfect! Thank you!
